# Как в таблице сделать полупрозрачный фон?

Tags: html, css

Хотелось бы, чтоб текст выделялся и не сливался с фоном, а полностью таблицу белой делать не хочется, так как надо, чтоб картинка была видна.

Answer (score 1):

Что именно надо сделать и какого цвета? Ничего непонятно.
Фон таблицы полупрозрачный - а за ним то что?

> ну как бы чтоб текст выделялся и не сливался с фоном

Так сделайте цвет шрифта и цвет фона разными.

Comment: за ним каринка у меня стоит)фон сайта)а на сайте таблица)надо чтоб был такой полупрозрачный фон таблицы чтобы и текст не сливался с фоном сайта)и фон сайта был виден)

Comment: Посмотрите насчёт CSS-свойста opacity, наверно, подойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

эээ, опасити не прокактит, т.к. сделает всю таблицу прозрачной...
выхода два:
 - background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); к примеру, для браузеров(chrome, ff, ie9) поддерживающих задание цвета в формате rgba. Последнее число - прозрачность, первых три 0-255 интенсивность цветового канала r, g, b
 - если надо для старых IE, то только через полупрозрачные картинки (png, gif). Если надо одним цветом то можно так:
 background: url(image.png) repeat; где image.png - картинка полупрозрачная размером 1*1пкс

если какой-то рисунок) то как обычно)

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать полупрозрачный PNG и поставить его в качестве background для таблицы, правда со старыми MSIE это не будет работать, но решать вам.